# external javascript function and html button

Tags: javascript, html

beginner to html, javascript, and stack overflow so take it easy on me. i am trying to get my html to pop up a display that will use the function of the external js file to do calculations, but for now i will keep it simple:

```
function findA(x, y, z) {
  var I = (x*100);
  var N = (y/100);
  var S = (z+50);
  document.write(x,y,z);
  }
```

that is all there is in the js file, now on to the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
     <body>
      <article>
       <form>
         <fieldset id="button">
          <input type="submit" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onsubmit='findA(1,5,8)'>
         </fieldset>
       </form>
      </article>
     </body>
```

thats it for the html. it should just display one button on html screen. not sure what to do afterwords so any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** *

my new code is this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
     <body>
      <article>
       <form>
         <fieldset id="button">
           <input type="button" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onclick='alert(monthly(1,5,8))'>
         </fieldset>
       </form>
      </article>
     </body>
```

and the js file is:

```
function monthly(x, y, z) {
 var I = (x*100);
 var N = (y/100); 
 var S = (z+50);
 var A = ("I: " + I + "N: " + N + " S: " + S);
 return A;
  }
```

yet nothing happens when i click calculate. i am using chrome to test this as well as Internet Explorer. i dont see what could be wrong about this. suggestion?

Comment: It is not exactly clear for me that, you want to achieve.
You want to write the output of your function to the top of your page, do you? Or want to shove in a popup?
I think <input> element should have closed like this ->
<input type="submit" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onsubmit='findA(1,5,8)'/>

Answer (score 1):

First, change your "`document.write`" to "`return`" in your javascript. document.write will erase the existing HTML in the document, and won't provide a popup you have asked for.

For the rest, there are a few approaches, but I'd offer that the simplest suggestion would be to take this line:

```
<input type="submit" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onsubmit='findA(1,5,8)'>
```

and change it to (updated):

```
<input type="button" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onclick='alert(monthly(1,5,8))'>
```

**EDIT:** The following jsfiddle works: (https://jsfiddle.net/7stL2cmL/12/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function monthly(x, y, z) {
    var I = (x * 100);
    var N = (y / 100);
    var S = (z + 50);
    var A = ("I: " + I + "N: " + N + " S: " + S);
    return A;
        }
        </script>
        </head>

    <article>
        <form>
            <fieldset id="button">
                <input type="button" id="submit" value="Calculate" onclick='alert(" dddd"+monthly(1,5,8))'>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </article>
</body>
```

Comment: nothing is happening for some reason. i see the logic of it but when i click calculate no pop up appears. i dont understand why this is happening. i changed the code: document.write(); to: return; as well as adding x y and z to a new var A (the sum) but nothing is working. i tried google chrome as well as Internet Explorer.

Comment: There! Needed to alert the function that actually returned a value. Document.write won't return anything. See how that works for you.

Comment: still nothing... im wondering if its some sort of error via browser (shouldnt be). ill post the new code i used ur code to change. check the edit part one more time.

Comment: Can you put it into a jsfiddle? Ican take a look there. Probably something simple.

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger or seeing what the console has to say? Might just be a subtle typo.

Comment: It's a website where you can paste in JS and run it live, then save it and post a URL to it for others to run/review. Very cool tool used a lot here at SO.

Comment: Just for grins, temporarily put your "monthly" function within the <HEAD> block of your page.

Comment: the answer below found it out. thanks though for your time

Comment: Just fixed it. Just a javascript declaration!

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick instead of onsubmit.

```js
function findA(x, y, z) {
  var I = (x*100);
  var N = (y/100);
  var S = (z+50);
  document.write(x,y,z);
  }
```

```html
<fieldset id="button">
   <input type="submit" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onclick='findA(1,5,8)'>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

first;: the html will show the button, but the document.write will never be seen by the user befouse is executed onsubmit  , if you wan to test you must edit the function like this

```
    function findA(x, y, z) {
      var I = (x*100);
      var N = (y/100);
      var S = (z+50);
      document.write(x,y,z);
      return false;
  }
```

and then in the html submit use:

```
<input type="submit" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onsubmit='return findA(1,5,8)'>
```

second: the script include it will work only for internet explorer 9 or less so if you are testing with a browser that doesn't match that version change the conditional include

Answer (score 0):

Nobody seems to notice, but your input element should have closed:

```
<input type="submit" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onsubmit='findA(1,5,8)'>
```

Like this:

```
<input type="submit" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onsubmit='findA(1,5,8)'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
     <body>
      <article>
       <form>
         <fieldset id="button">
          <input type="submit" id= "submit" value= "Calculate" onclick='findA(1,5,8)'>
         </fieldset>
       </form>
      </article>
     </body>
```

change to onsubmit to onclick as you haven't used a form there.

new javascript code to display popup

```
function findA(x, y, z) {
            var I = (x*100);
            var N = (y/100);
            var S = (z+50);
            alert(I+N+S);
        }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

One question, **Is the external file  main.js?** If so then only IE9 and below will be able to understand the conditional comments `<!--[if lt IE 9]> ... <![endif]-->`. Place the reference to the **main.js** outside the conditional comments like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

For more details about conditional comments you can refer http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: wow thanks that did it. i thought that comment was meant for IE 9 and above.